# Where to find jquery UI Tabs widget API document

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I find someone write the jquery codes as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function (e, tab) {
            alert("The tab at index " + tab.index + " was selected");
        });
    });
 </script>
```

He binds the 'tabsselect' event.
I try to find more detail about tabselect event.So I visit the URL:http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

But I didn't find the tabselect event. Did I visit the wrong URL?
or anything I was misleaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select event was renamed to activate in 1.9: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

There's documentation for 1.8 as well, including the select event: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/#event-select

The select event was deprecated, so it still works in 1.9, unless you set `$.uiBackCompat = false`. More info in the 1.9 upgrade guide: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#preparing-for-jquery-ui-1-10

Answer (score 1):

Before jQueryUI changed their site a few months ago, the documentation existed. You can also use:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   select:function(eventt,ui){
        alert("The tab at index " + ui.index + " was selected");
   }
});
```

If you want to see more detail as to what is available in the `ui` object ( or `tab` in your code), log it to a console.